# RubyMotion with CoreAnimation constant issue

Tags: rubymotion

I'm trying to use some CATransition constants in my rubymotion app thusly:

```
transition = CATransition.animation
transition.duration = 0.4
transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom
```

But am getting undefined local variable or method `kCATransitionMoveIn'. I've added quartzcore to frameworks in my rake file:

app.frameworks += ['CoreLocation', 'MapKit', 'QuartzCore']

Does anyone know why I can't access this constant? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constants in Ruby can't start with a lowercase letter. You'll want to use `KCATransitionMoveIn` and `KCATransitionFromBottom`.